# Untraditional gradient pattern programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a programmatically a barTint color to my navigationBar. However i don't want the traditional 2 color pattern. I want to create something similar to below image. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Chameleon](https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon#gradient-colors-1) library to create gradient color. Then proceed with the example to create UIColor:

```
UIColor(gradientStyle:UIGradientStyle, withFrame:CGRect, andColors:[UIColor])
```

Comment: i don't wanna be locked to specific colors

Comment: You don't have to, you are selecting colors in array, you can choose between which color you wanna use. You can pass any UIColor there.

Comment: But will this give me this effect with gradient in both sites in the corners?

Comment: This will give you similar effect with `UIGradientStyle.Radial`. If you want exact effect, you have to try `CAGradientLayer`.

Comment: And how do i control the size of the gradient circle?